# Parse query on array of pointers only retrieving first object

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, pointers, parse-platform

In the code below, `self.arrayOfLikers` is an array of Pointers to Parse User Objects. Which looks like this on Parse:

[image: what my array on Parse looks like]

```
 var query = PFQuery(className: "Item")

    query.includeKey("likedBy")


    query.getObjectInBackgroundWithId(theObjectIdOfTheItem!) { (returnedItem, error) in

        if error != nil {
            print(error)
        }

        else {

            returnedItem?.fetchInBackgroundWithBlock({ (fetchedReturnedItem, error) in

                if error != nil {
                    print(error)
                }

                else {

                    dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue(),{

                        self.arrayOfLikers = fetchedReturnedItem!["likedBy"] as! [PFUser]

                        print("about to print the arrayOfLikers")

                        print(self.arrayOfLikers)

                        self.tableView.reloadData()

                    })
                }

            })

        }

    }
```

When I print my `self.arrayOfLikers` I can see that the first index contains a correctly retrieved PFUser object. Below is a print statement from Xcode:

[image: xcode print statement]

In another viewController, I am storing these pointers when the user taps the "like" button. This is how I am storing those pointers:

---

Creation of the userPointer:

`let userPointer = PFObject(outDataWithClassName: "User", objectId: user?.objectId)`

(oddly, the Parse docs use `withoutDataWithClassName`, but when I put this in, Xcode keeps making me change it `outDataWithClassName`, and it compiles, so I guess this is correct?)

---

Storing the userPointer: (please note, `theItemObject` is an object set by a previous VC):

`theItemObject!.addObject(userPointer, forKey: "likedBy")`

---

Consequently, Parse via Xcode gives me this error:

> 2016-03-30 23:38:47.749 Trashly[5482:1512409] [Error]: object not found for get (Code: 101, Version: 1.12.0)
>   Optional(Error Domain=Parse Code=101 "object not found for get" UserInfo={code=101, temporary=0, error=object not found for get, NSLocalizedDescription=object not found for get})

---

Any ideas why my query is not getting any user objects but the first one?

Comment: This question has been answered by @Shubhank . Waiting for him to leave a solution so I can accept it!

Comment: I should add the solution. It is simple enough. Instead of creating a user pointer for the "likes", I simply store the current user in the "likedBy" array. Parse automatically stores it as a pointer. Simple.